# Not able to see the content of POI Excel Header

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I am creating POI Excel sheet with a header, although header is getting created but every time after downloading the excel I have to enable header to see the header content. Please help me so that when I download and open the excel sheet, I do not have to click on header option in insert tab to see the header file.

This is the code I have used to create the header .

```
XSSFWorkbook  workbookuse = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheetuse = workbookuse.createSheet("Usage_Report"); 
     Header header = sheetuse.getHeader();
                header.setCenter(HSSFHeader.font("Calibri", "Bold") +
                        generatedUseFileName.substring(0,11));

                    header.setLeft("Test Data");

                header.setRight("Test Data");
```

I am using office 2016.

Comment: How are you setting the header to the sheet ??

Comment: The above code I am using which create header for the sheet .sheetuse is the instance of sheet

Comment: Code is added now .